# setState not mutating while calling a function multiple times

Tags: javascript, reactjs, chat, setstate, pubnub

I am using PubNub SDK for Implementing Chat with React components..
I am stuck in refreshing the state due to async nature of setting state.. below is some code to illustrate how this works.

```
const handleNewChannelCreation = async (newChannelId: string) => {
    const newChannelMetadata = (await pubnub.objects.getChannelMetadata({ channel: newChannelId })).data
    setCurrentChannelMetadata(newChannelMetadata ? newChannelMetadata : dummyChannelMetadata)

    if (channelMetadata) {
      const filteredChannels = channelMetadata.filter(isChannel)
      const isNewChannel = filteredChannels.findIndex((channel) => channel.id === newChannelMetadata.id)

      // the api can return an existing channel therefore we need to check if the channel already exists
      if (isNewChannel === -1) {
        console.log("handleNewChannelCreation__", filteredChannels.length, "newChannel", newChannelMetadata.name)

        setNewChannels(newChannels.concat(newChannelMetadata)) // this is not ideal I know and this dont work as this function is called multiple times. 
      }
    }

    setIsModalOpen(false)
  }
```

Comment: Not exactly sure what you are trying to do but it sounds like you want to setState based on a previous state change but you need to make sure the previous state change has been persisted first. You would need to be listening for those state change events and only respond when you get that callback. I would send this issue to support@pubnub.com with SDK logs and full code if you want this resolved quickly. Free support is best effort but it is still prompt.

Answer (score 0):

If you are enqueueing state updates in a loop or multiples within a single render cycle then you'll typically want to use functional state updates so you update from the previous state and ***not*** *some* state value closed over in callback scope. In your case you are appending a new value to an array *from* the previous state, so there's a dependency here on the previous state.

[Functional State Updates](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#functional-updates)

> If the new state is computed using the previous state, you can pass a
> function to `setState`. The function will receive the previous value,
> and return an updated value.

```
setNewChannels(newChannels => newChannels.concat(newChannelMetadata))
```